# Recursive function in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, recursion, tree

I have the following function in my c# silverlight application to find the total sub nodes of a node in the tree

```
        //get total children
    private int getTotalChildren(int id) 
    {
        int total=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < persons.Count;i++ )
        {
            if (persons[i].Manager == id)
            {
                total += 1;
                total += getTotalChildren(persons[i].Id);
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
```

the line total += getTotalChildren(persons[i].id) is making the browser windows auto close when i run it (i am guessing thats silverlights way of crashing?) in the IDE I don't get any errors.

edit: I don't see how it could be infinite recursion since there is no person which has itself as manager. persons is a List built using this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<Persons>
    <Person>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>temp</Name>
        <Qlid>1234</Qlid>
        <Manager>0</Manager>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>someone</Name>
        <Qlid>5678</Qlid>
        <Manager>1</Manager>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <Name>wefwef</Name>
        <Qlid>3333</Qlid>
        <Manager>1</Manager>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <Name>batman</Name>
        <Qlid>6723</Qlid>
        <Manager>3</Manager>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Id>5</Id>
        <Name>batman</Name>
        <Qlid>6723</Qlid>
        <Manager>3</Manager>
    </Person>
</Persons>
```

edit2: ok sorry guys, it was something really stupid . It was a circular loop I thought I had made a shortcut to the xml file on my desktop but instead accidentaly made a copy. person 1 had person 3 as its manager who had person 1 as manager  in the file the program was reading while I was editing the copy

Comment: I don't know enough about silverlight to say if the "auto close" is normal behavior, but I know enough about C# to recommend that you put a try catch around the offending code. Put a label on your page and if the exception is hit change the text value of the label to ex.ToString(). This should give you more information on what's going on.

Comment: How is persons stored? I'm not sure I understand why this needs to be recursive.

Comment: Are you sure it's not infinite recursion? Depending on what tree this is, it could keep calling itself for the same two IDs.

Comment: @paper: you'd have to know the data to be sure of that.

Comment: Everyone's pretty much saying the same thing but we forgot to give the solution - you need an anchor. See, what's going on is you keep on cycling through people, then tell yourself to repeat the process. There's no point where you stop going in a loop. Without an anchor to tell the code "OK, you don't have to call yourself again" you'll go on forever and eventually crash.

Comment: @diadem: woudln't it stop when it comes to a node who is not the manager of anyone
and yes that is the actual list

Comment: @anon2: Yes, you are right. I made an invalid assumption. Your best bet is to put the try catch block up to give us the proper direction of what's going on. At least I'll learn from this mistake and not do it in the future.

Comment: @anon2: I don't see anything in the example you've shown.  However we still don't know what `Type` the identifier `persons` is.  It doesn't appear to be the XML itself since it at least has ordinal indexer that returns an object that has a `Manager` property.  I suspect you have deserialised the XML in to a set of objects.  Are you sure this deserialisation has completed correctly?  For example if all the `Manager` properties are 0 you'd have an infinite loop.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones persons is a list of type Person, which is my small custom class with get set properties with all the info. I am displaying the data in a gridview in my application and it looks ok

Comment: In C# the default value for an integer is 0 if it is not set. If you pass in 0 for the initial id and every person object is not set then both the ID and manager field for every person would be 0.

Comment: @anon2: Have you opened your computer and checked for gremlins? Up voting because the solution isn't obvious.

Any word on the try catch result? Is the label changed or does the browser still just close anyhow?

Comment: ok sorry guys, it was something really stupid . It was a circular loop I thought I had made a shortcut to the xml file on my desktop but instead accidentaly made a copy. person 1 had person 3 as its manager who had person 1 as manager in the file the program was reading while I was editing the copy

Comment: @anon2: I'm still glad you found the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Speculation] You may be crashing due to a stack overflow caused by infinite recursion. Does your contain a member whose manager is the id itself? This would cause your recursion to never end and lead to a stack overflow.

```
private int getTotalChildren(int id) 
{
    int total=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < persons.Count;i++ )
    {
        if (persons[i].Manager == id)
        {
            total += 1;
            if(persons[i].Manager != persons[i].Id)
            {
                total += getTotalChildren(persons[i].Id);
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be a direct loop either - it could be a is the manager of b who is the manager of c who is the manager of a (circular reference).

Answer (score 1):

You aren't specifying the child nodes anywhere. You always look at persons, which isn't changing.

Comment: I made a false assumption and apologize. Given your new information I have to think on it.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, Silverlight has a "recursion limit" designed to help avoid code that freezes the user's browser. If you Google around for "Silverlight recursion" or similar you'll find a few links.

I don't know a ton about it, but my guess is that you'll simply need to do this a different way.

Comment: that really sucks, but my test data is so small I doubt it goes over their limit, whatever that is

Answer (score 0):

Protip:  consider a for/while loop instead of incurring the frame memory overhead associated with recusion for *simple* scenarios like this.

Remember, everything you can accomplish with recusion can be accomplished without it.  A seasoned developer knows when to sacrifice performance for readability.